# Getting/Setting CaseComment Privacy

Tags: c#, .net, public

According to the API documentation, in order to get/set the CaseComment privacy, you need to use the `IsPublished` field. However, whenever a comment is posted into Salesforce, it always seems to default to Public, and must be set to private manually by clicking the "Make Private" button. I'm not entirely sure how to remedy this.

If I use the API to create a comment, and I set the `IsPublished` field to false, it is always public.

CaseComments are pushed to our own web service using an Apex Trigger, and we create CaseComments via the Enterprise API. However, I can't seem to make the privacy work no matter what I do. What are my options?

Answer (score 0):

I threw together this quick test from .NET against the Partner API. It's using our custom wrapper around that API. It should be easy enough to see how it corresponds to the API.

```
SalesforceSession salesforceSession = // Setup the Salesforce Session...

Case testCase = new Case();

CaseService caseService = new CaseService(salesforceSession);
SaveResult caseSaveResult = caseService.Insert(testCase);
Assert.IsTrue(caseSaveResult.success);

CaseComment testCaseComment = new CaseComment();
testCaseComment.ParentId = testCase.Id;
testCaseComment.IsPublished = false;
testCaseComment.CommentBody = "Unpublished";

CaseCommentService caseCommentService = new CaseCommentService(salesforceSession);
SaveResult caseCommentSaveResult = caseCommentService.Insert(testCaseComment);
Assert.IsTrue(caseCommentSaveResult.success);

CaseComment retreved = caseCommentService.GetByEntityId(testCaseComment.Id);

Assert.AreEqual(testCaseComment.IsPublished, retreved.IsPublished);
```

The assertions all pass. So, from the API perspective I created a CaseComment that had `IsPublished == false`.

It looked right in the UI as well under the case.
[image]

Maybe you have a trigger or some other process that is making it public after insertion?